# SAMSUNG scanner not found, printing works (18.04)

Tags: drivers, scanner, samsung

Samsung Xpress M2027 WiFi Printer.
Official Samsung drivers installed and printing works. Printer connected over WiFi and Google Cloud as well. Scanning doesn't work, Ubuntu does not see the scanner:

sudo sane-find-scanner does not find the printer:

```
  # sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the
  # result is different from what you expected, first make sure your
  # scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.

  # No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.

  # No USB scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel driver for your USB host controller and have setup
  # the USB system correctly. See man sane-usb for details.

  # Not checking for parallel port scanners.

  # Most Scanners connected to the parallel port or other proprietary ports
  # can't be detected by this program.
```

Comment: Another such questions with up votes, no answers. :(

Comment: I got 109 questions related to "Samsung scanner" one with 10 answers.

Comment: To use the scanner, you probably have to connect to the Samsung via a USB cable.

Answer (score 0):

You need the Samsung drivers from HP (HP bought Samsung printer line, I think). Other alternative is to install the original Samsung drivers or use the SULDR repository: https://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/